# CockroachDB Docker Compose Script with SQL commands

Tags: bash, docker-compose, cockroachdb

I would like to accomplish 2 things:

1) Start a CockroachDB cluster with docker compose (works)

2) Execute SQL commands on the cluster (I want to create a Database)

My Docker File Looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services: 
roach-ui: 
 image: cockroachdb/cockroach
 command: start --insecure
 expose:
  - "8080"
  - "26257"
 ports:
  - "26257:26257"
  - "8080:8080"
 networks:
  - roachnet
db-1: 
 image: cockroachdb/cockroach
 command: start --insecure --join=roach-ui
 networks:
  - roachnet
 volumes: 
  - ./data/db-1:/cockroach/cockroach-data

networks:
 roachnet:
```

When I run docker-compose up, everything works as expected.
While using google, I found that the solution is to run a bash script, I created the following setup.sh:

```
sql --insecure --execute="CREATE TABLE testDB"
```

I tried to run the script via command: bash -c "setup.sh", but Docker says that it can not run the command "bash".
Any Suggestions ? Thanks :)

EDIT:

I am running docker-compose up, the error I am getting:

```
roach-ui_1  | Failed running "bash"
heimdall_roach-ui_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Would you mind copying and pasting the specific Docker command you're running and the error message you're getting into the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So what you need is an extra init service to initialize the DB. This service will run a bash script to execute commands that will init the DB

**setup_db.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Wait for servers to be up
sleep 10

HOSTPARAMS="--host db-1 --insecure"
SQL="/cockroach/cockroach.sh sql $HOSTPARAMS"

$SQL -e "CREATE DATABASE tarun;"
$SQL -d tarun -e "CREATE TABLE articles(name VARCHAR);"
```

And then you add this file to execute in the `docker-compose.yml`

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  roach-ui:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach
    command: start --insecure
    expose:
     - "8080"
     - "26257"
    ports:
     - "26257:26257"
     - "8080:8080"
    networks:
     - roachnet
  db-1:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach
    command: start --insecure --join=roach-ui
    networks:
     - roachnet
    volumes:
     - ./data/db-1:/cockroach/cockroach-data
  db-init:
   image: cockroachdb/cockroach
   networks:
    - roachnet
   volumes:
     - ./setup_db.sh:/setup_db.sh
   entrypoint: "/bin/bash"
   command: /setup_db.sh
networks:
  roachnet:
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer! One divergence that I made was to use [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) (with `db-1` as the value) in the `db-init` service to make sure it runs after the DB has started, rather than using `sleep` in the script.

Comment: Ideal way is to use a combination of depends_on and https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: You're right—I actually had to reintroduce your `sleep 10` line to ensure a successful connection.